# Split a column with varying delimiters into 2, along with unfortunate fraction structure

Tags: r, split

I am fairly new to R and programming in general.  I was given a data set to work with that unfortunately was structured fairly rough.

It is in the form of

W-X/Y"-Z

The first number being inches, however for values <1 inch it is simply

X/Y"-Z

I need a way to:
a) split Z off, (the number after the last delimiter of "-"

as well as

b) convert the W-X/Y" or X/Y" value to its decimal equivalent. 
So 1-1/2" to just 1.5

So split the original column into 2 columns, one with the Z value, and one with the decimal inches value.  As shown below

```
    input        length           bin
3-1/2"-14           3.5            14
  3/4"-20           .75            20
```

Comment: If you can show some real data and expected output, it will be easier

Comment: Edited with a table.  The input being what I'll have, and I'd like the 2 output columns on the right.

Comment: Posted a solution based on the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `split` the 'input' column by the last `-` or `""` to get a `list` output.  Loop over the `list` (with `lapply`), remove the blank elements (`x[nzchar(x)]`), replace the `-` with `+`, use `eval(parse` to evaluate the fraction to get the numeric output, concatenate with the second value, `rbind` the `list` elements, and assign (`<-`) the output to create two new columns.

```
df1[c("length", "bin")] <-  do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(df1$input, 
                '-(?=[^-]+$)|"', perl=TRUE), function(x) {
                   x1 <- x[nzchar(x)]
                   c(eval(parse(text=sub("-", "+", x1[1]))), as.numeric(x1[2]))}))

df1
#      input length bin
#1 3-1/2"-14   3.50  14
#2   3/4"-20   0.75  20
```

NOTE: If the "input" column is `factor` class, convert to `character` and use it in `strsplit` ,i.e. `strsplit(as.character(df1$input), ...`

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(input=c('3-1/2"-14', '3/4"-20'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```